# Parameters for Numerics.IEqualityOperators Are Nullable?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, interface, nullable

With the creation of C# 11, static abstract operators are now allowed to be defined in interfaces. Because of this, the .NET Core 7 library now includes the interfaces `System.Numerics.IEqualityOperators` and `System.Numerics.IComparisonOperators`.

The `IComparisonOperators` interface is defined somewhat as I would expect:

```
namespace System.Numerics;
public interface IComparisonOperators<TSelf, TOther, TResult>
    : IEqualityOperators<TSelf, TOther, TResult>
    where TSelf : IComparisonOperators<TSelf, TOther, TResult>?
{
    static abstract TResult operator <(TSelf left, TOther right);
    static abstract TResult operator >(TSelf left, TOther right);
    static abstract TResult operator <=(TSelf left, TOther right);
    static abstract TResult operator >=(TSelf left, TOther right);
}
```

However, take a look at the `IEqualityOperators` interface:

```
namespace System.Numerics;
public interface IEqualityOperators<TSelf, TOther, TResult>
    where TSelf : IEqualityOperators<TSelf, TOther, TResult>?
{
    static abstract TResult operator ==(TSelf? left, TOther? right);
    static abstract TResult operator !=(TSelf? left, TOther? right);
}
```

The parameters to the two operators are suddenly nullable! Why would the equality operators be nullable if the comparison operators were not?

Additionally, in both interfaces, the `?` operator is also used in the type constraints. I know that `T?` is equivalent to `Nullable<T>`, but cannot understand it in the context of type constraints. Is it requiring `TSelf` to inherit from `System.Nullable`? I wasn't even aware that was possible!

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!